# How to convert Snowflake timestamp to Date

Tags: java, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

can anyone help me suggest how can i convert snowflake ltz timestamp to given date using java?

Sample in snowflake ltz format:
1658443006.285000000

Comment: When you query Snowflake to obtain the data, wrap the column with the time stamp with the to_date() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use smart objects, not dumb text

While I do not use Snowflake, a quick look at [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz) shows that their `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` type is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

### `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

So the appropriate class in Java is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Assuming the Snowflake JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can extract an object rather than mere text from the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

When writing to the database:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

If you want to view this moment as seen in a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Parsing text

You said:

> Sample in snowflake ltz format: 1658443006.285000000

Can you cite the documentation on that? I see no such format in their page on `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` data type.

At any rate, I imagine the text you give represents a number of whole seconds since an epoch reference, along with a fractional second with nanosecond resolution.

Assuming the epoch reference is the first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z), we can easily parse that as a `java.time.Instant` object in Java. But I *strongly* urge you to use objects instead of this approach, as discussed above.

Split the input into two parts, two strings. Parse each a 64-bit `long` integer number.

To do the split, we must escape the FULL STOP character with a pair of REVERSE SOLIDUS characters.

```
String[] parts = "1658443006.285000000".split( "\\." ) ;
long seconds = Long.parseLong( parts [ 0 ] ) ;
long nanos = Long.parseLong( parts [ 1 ] ) ;
```

Use a factory method to instantiate a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds , nanos ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/UHHy5g).

> instant.toString() → 2022-07-21T22:36:46.285Z

An `Instant` is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC, meaning an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero.

If you want to view this moment as seen in a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zit.toString() → 2022-07-22T07:36:46.285+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

Comment: One thing to note is that many drivers will translate timestamp_ltz to the local time zone of the caller.  You may want to consider converting to timestamp_ntz

Comment: @JimDemitriou A properly written JDBC driver should *not* inject a current default time zone into the mix. Unfortunately, many other tools and middleware may do so. In my experience (albeit, no Snowflake experience), the Java JDBC code above should avoid such an unfortunate anti-feature, and should return a value in UTC from a database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, as is required by the JDBC standard.

Comment: There have been reported behaviors that vary (just a quick Google showed some 3rd party products deviated from expectations) - I would think most programmers would want something deterministic that doesn’t leave the result to chance, and align with your answer: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#binding-variables-to-timestamp-columns

Comment: BTW- the timestamp_ltz format is intended for “local time zone”, you need to wrap the result with a conversion to NTZ (no time zone) in Snowflake to obtain UTC.